# Weird file not found error

Tags: ubuntu, jad

So I run the following queries,

```
ls
helloWorld.class  jad  Readme.txt

file jad
jad: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses  shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped

./jad helloWorld.class 
-bash: ./jad: No such file or directory
```

So it looks like `jad` is being detected as an argument for other commands, but when I use `jad` as a command, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
It might be a 32-bit vs 64-bit thing or something else. But downloading the statically linked version from here:
http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/
solved my case.